# CMake: Don't add header files of dependency library to the project (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, header

I'm using CMake for a project (lets call it "LibMain"). In the CMakeLists.txt (root directory) I include a dependency library ("LibDependency") that uses CMake as well:

```
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dependencies/libdep")
target_link_libraries("LibMain" PRIVATE "LibDependency")
```

The resulting Visual Studio solution contains 2 projects (besides the ALL_BUILD, INSTALL, ...):

- LibDependency
- LibMain

That's ok so far, but here is the part that bothers me: The "LibMain" project contains all header files of the dependency library in addition to the header files of the actual "LibMain" project.

Is there any way to tell CMake to exclude the "inherited" header files without messing up the include pathes?

Comment: I just realized it works like i want, if I change the scope of target_sources() for "LibDependency" from PUBLIC to PRIVATE. Is it generally spoken a good thing for a library to use PRIVATE for its header files? I used to declare only source as PRIVATE and headers as PUBLIC.

Comment: Is there a reason you add the headers of LibDependency to its target? This is unusual, although it occurs sometimes. Just adding sources should work for most use cases.

Comment: I like to have the headers included in the resulting Visual Studio solution while developing so I can easily open and modify them. For now I worked around my original issue by changing the scope of all header files from the LibDependency to PRIVATE.

Comment: Unfortunately, pulling projects in with `add_subdirectory` is quite fragile and requires some extent of support from the project being pulled in. Most projects don't care about this use case and thus don't work very well when being pulled in like this. A cleaner solution is to build the dependency in isolation, and then pull in the binaries via conventional means (possibly in the form of a 'superbuild' CMake script).

Comment: Thats wouldn't be a problem in this case as both libraries are developed by us. Is there any documentation / best practice paper in case we want to stick with `add_subdirectory`?